Ranking/unranking A-restricted compositions
This might be quite a challenging question, so any help is a appreciated.
I want to enumerate in a sensible way all bosonic states of n=1,2,...,N particles in L sites with maximal occupation per site M<N. Mathematically, this corresponds to finding and enumerating all the A-restricted compositions of N elements in L bins, where the restricting subset A is A={1,2,...,M}.
Ideally I would like to have both an "absolute" rank and a "relative" rank. By that I mean that I start from enumerating all states with n=1 particles in L sites, then all the n=2 states, and so on until n=N (at some point, the M restriction will kick in).
At every level n, I have a relative ranking for that level, but I also want to keep track of a cumulative absolute ranking that takes into account the number of all previous compositions at the lower levels. This is because in my eventual code (exact diagonalization), I might need to jump from one level to another when particles are added or removed.
I have a working algorithm in python that does the enumeration without the capping M (in the code notation, N=n, L=k), and I also have a ranking function (I didn't figure out the unranking one yet though...):

def first_state_lex_multi(n, k):
    x = [0] * k
    x[-1] = n
    return x

def last_state_lex_multi(n, k):
    x = [0] * k 
    x[0] = n
    return x

def next_state_lex_multi(x):

    v = x[0]
    x[0] = 0
    j = 1
    while (0==x[j]):
        j += 1
    x[j] -= 1
    x[j-1] = 1 + v

    return x

def colexRank_multi(conf):

    N = np.sum(conf)
    L = len(conf)

    previous_conf_num=0
    for n in range(1,N):
        previous_conf_num += binomial(n + L - 1, n)

    rel_rank = 0
    for k in range(1,L):
        rel_rank += binomial(N + k - 1 - np.sum(conf[k:]), k)

    abs_rank = previous_conf_num + rel_rank

    return rel_rank, abs_rank


def generate_composition_reverse(n,k):

    x = first_state_lex_multi(n, k)    
    x_last = last_state_lex_multi(n, k)

    while x != x_last:
        print("composition:", x)  
        rel, abs = colexRank_multi(x)
        print("rel index:", rel)
        print("abs index:", abs)
  
        x = next_state_lex_multi(x)

    print("composition:", x)  
    rel, abs = colexRank_multi(x)
    print("rel index:", rel)
    print("abs index:", abs)


If I want to simply generate all the states in sequence, I can recursively call this algorithm with increasing values of N and keep track of each iteration step and use that to generate both the relative and absolute ranks, e.g. I can simply discard/reject the states whose population goes above the capping. I can then save each state and its indices in a python dictionary for quickly lookup via hashing.
This works, but since I don't know in the future how many of these states I will need to generate, I'm a bit afraid that the hash used under the hood by the dictionary might require lots of memory (e.g. for millions of states). The lookup operation is O(1) and much faster than evaluating a ranking/unranking function which as far as I understand can only be O(N), BUT the latter does not have memory restrictions.
Any ideas/pointers? Any help is deeply appreciated.
